# Exception on edit in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to edit a record of an employee in MVC using entity framework. Here is the code:

#### Action

```
public ActionResult EditEmployee(EmployeeList2 emp2, int Id = 0)
{

    empEntities = new EmployeeDBEntities2();
    employeeTbl objEmployee = empEntities.employeeTbls.First(m => m.empId == Id);/**/ERROR**
            objEmployee.empName = emp2.EmployeeListDetail.Name;
    objEmployee.empAge = emp2.EmployeeListDetail.Age;
    objEmployee.empDob = emp2.EmployeeListDetail.Dob;
    return RedirectToAction("EmployeeList2", "Employee");
    // rest of the code
}
```

#### View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditEmployee", "BootStrap", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    <div class="modal fade mymodal" id="openDialogDiv">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button data-dismiss="modal" class="close"><span>&times;</span></button>
                    <div class="modal-title">Edit Employee Record</div>
                </div>
                // rest of the code
```

But I am getting an error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

This code is working fine when used in another place.

Comment: what are the values of the emp2 and Id parameters in EditEmployee action method?

Comment: emp2 is a list of employee contains Name,Age etc of one employee on given Id

Comment: are they getting populated(emp2 and Id)?

Comment: Yes they are getting populated with data. And as i have already mentioned same code works perfectly at another place

Comment: the id value is not present in the table. when you do first() on the null you get exception. that might be the reason. put a break point and let us know the value

Comment: I did not cared that Id is 0 and emp2 is full with data so that exception is coming but why Id is not coming from view

Comment: can you post the complete view which contains the data being posted?

Answer (score 0):

It seems this code

```
employeeTbl objEmployee = empEntities.employeeTbls.First(m => m.empId == Id);
```

is returning null so assigning will result on that exception

```
objEmployee.empName = emp2.EmployeeListDetail.Name;
objEmployee.empAge = emp2.EmployeeListDetail.Age;
objEmployee.empDob = emp2.EmployeeListDetail.Dob;
```

try using FirstOrDefault

```
employeeTbl objEmployee = empEntities.employeeTbls.FirstOrDefault(m => m.empId == Id);
if(objEmployee==null)
   return HttpNotFound("No record found.");

objEmployee.empName = emp2.EmployeeListDetail.Name;
objEmployee.empAge = emp2.EmployeeListDetail.Age;
objEmployee.empDob = emp2.EmployeeListDetail.Dob;
```

Comment: I did not cared that Id is 0 and emp2 is full with data so that exception is coming but why Id is not coming from view

Comment: Not sure since we cant see the actual code of your view, you need to post the actual view for others to see as well.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the id parameter is set to the default - 0 or to a wrong id that isn't in the db?
Where you are getting the error, it makes the most sense. follow with the debugger.
You can use this code.

```
[HttpPost]
            public ActionResult EditEmployee(EmployeeList2 emp2, int Id = 0)
            {
                empEntities = new EmployeeDBEntities2();
                employeeTbl objEmployee = empEntities.employeeTbls.FirstOrDefault(m => m.empId == Id);
                if(objEmployee!= null)
                {
                    objEmployee.empName = emp2.EmployeeListDetail.Name;
                    objEmployee.empAge = emp2.EmployeeListDetail.Age;
                    objEmployee.empDob = emp2.EmployeeListDetail.Dob;
                 }
    return RedirectToAction("EmployeeList2", "Employee");   
}
```

**Notice that if 'id' is 0 then you have a problem with the view/routing of 'id' and we need to see the code to help**

Comment: I am getting error at below line
employeeTbl objEmployee = empEntities.employeeTbls.FirstOrDefault(m => m.empId == Id);
And if I use FirstOrDefault I get same error but at next line means objEmployee is null

Comment: yes you were right. I did not cared that Id is 0 and emp2 is full with data so that exception is coming but why Id is not coming from view

Comment: id isn't coming because:
 you didn't transfer it properly from view, or you are using a different routing. If you have the id in the emp2 parameter, then use it, if not, then post your view and routing config.

Comment: I am new to MVC so can i know how to pass Id from view,actually I am using my view for two purpose,one for displaying record and another for edit record(by using bootstrap popup)

Comment: try this: 
' employeeTbl objEmployee = empEntities.employeeTbls.FirstOrDefault(m => m.empId == emp2.Id);'
Usually this is how you transfer id from **edit page**.

Comment: From other pages you can transfer 'id' with this code:  `@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditBranch", new { id=item.ID })`